# WCF Buffer Pools

Tags: wcf, buffer, message-queue

I have been reading a number of article on WCF Buffer Pools and can't seem to figure it out.  I have a queued wcf service (net.msmq) that accepts a string as a parameter.  If the service gets hammered (say it gets 64 insances pulling messages off the queue) the RAM jumps up pretty high (say around 300MB based off of 1MB messages in the queue).  After the queue is processed that memory doesn't get released.  My questions are:

1. What size objects go to large heap?  Is it 85k?
2. Say if messages will always be 1MB, should my max buffer size be 1MB?
3. If max buffer size is 1MB and I expect 64 instances, should max pool be 64MB?
4. How can I get my service to release unused memory?  I heard that large heap doesn't get cleaned up unless you cycle app pool.  Is this correct?

I basically want to setup the service so it can get hammered and recover (freeing up memory for other services when it is idle).